# Fixed size LinkedHashMap memory leak?

Tags: java, caching, memory-leaks, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to use LinkedHashMap as a local FIFO cache solution overwriting its removeEldestEntry method to keep size fixed:

```
Map lhm = new LinkedHashMap(MAX_CACHE_SIZE + 1, .75F, false) {
   protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
      return size() > MAX_CACHE_SIZE;
   }
};
```

but when I constantly add new entries to the map monitoring process memory I see it keeps growing until max virtual machine memory is used though map size doesn't increase.

Is it by design? Why does it need more memory if old values are discarded and size of the map is limited?

UPDATE:
as requested I'm attaching full code:

```
@Test
public void mapMemory() {
    final int MAX_CACHE_SIZE = (int) 1E3;
    Map lhm = new LinkedHashMap(MAX_CACHE_SIZE + 1, 1F, false) {
       protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
          return size() > MAX_CACHE_SIZE;
       }
    };

    for (long i = 0; i < 1E10; i++) {
        lhm.put("key_" + i, "VALUE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an actual FIFO data structure instead of trying to emulate one with a HashMap?

Comment: I need it to be able to retrieve value by a key. What are FIFO solutions for that?

Answer (score 2):

A blog post explaining memory leak issue with LinkedHashMap in multi-thread context

https://hoangx281283.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/wrong-use-of-linkedhashmap-causes-memory-leak/

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in your constructor defines loadFactor, multiplied by your 1st parameter (map size) it gives you the value (size) that triggers the resize of you map. So in your case you should (probably) use loadFactor = 1.

EDIT:
Your memory leak is caused by something that you DON'T show us, your code as above will NEVER cause a memory leak.
Check where you may be keeping references to old values/objects. Map in itself would NOT cause memory leak - if it did ALL systems using maps (and there are lots of them) would be crashing every few hours.

Comment: Doesn't work. As I described in the question, map size doesn't increase. But memory usage does.

Comment: When the map is resized it increases the capacity, NOT it's size. The value is the trigger point when the map is resized. At resize the map reserves MORE MEMORY to be able to use it later. Default increment factor is 2, so the memory usage (nearly) doubled.

Comment: BTW: what "does not work" and in what way? If it is your TV that "does not work" then I will not be able to help you - too far away

Comment: "does not work" means memory usage reaches maximum virtual machine memory available.I tried with different load factor and initial capacity values and it's the same.

Comment: As I said in the edited answer: map in itself will NOT cause memory leak. Check your code for references to old (discarded) values/objects

Comment: It's not real memory leak as there is no OOM exception. I only wonder why does it need all memory available. If I limit VM memory to much lower value it still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need random access to the collection's contents then it's not really a FIFO.

It should be noted that collections don't store objects though, they store references to objects which is an important distinction.  Storing the same object in 2 different collections won't have significant memory overhead so maybe your best solution it to store the same object into both a Queue and a Map, use the Queue when you need FIFO behaviour an the Map when you need random access.

You do have to remember to remove the object from both collections when you're done with it though, otherwise it won't be GC'd.

Comment: Ok, I can think about writing my own implementation using both structures.
But do I really need it if there is already solution I provided in question? I only wanted to know if this extensive memory usage is something I should worry about.

Comment: Having a class that handles it all for you would be more in keeping with good OO, as you can reuse it in other projects.